# Angular2 - Compare two control values using custom Validator

Tags: validation, angular2-forms, custom-validators, angular2-formbuilder

I need to validate two form control values using custom validator. It should be done using formbuilder.

```
Component.ts

  this.mainForm = this.fb.group({
      fromtotal: [0, [Validators.Required]],
      toTotal: [0, [Validators.Required]],
      option: [value, Validators.required]
    });
```

Here I need to add custom validator where fromTotal and tototal should be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [ngModel]="user.password" 
        required **validateEqual="confirmPassword"** reverse="true" #password="ngModel">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Retype password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" [ngModel]="user.confirmPassword" 
        required **validateEqual="password"** reverse="false" #confirmPassword="ngModel">
    </div>
```

Comment: I need custom validator to do this.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
// import here your EqualsValidator
import { EqualsValidator} from '...';

...
...
...

this.mainForm = this.fb.group({
  fromtotal: [0, [Validators.Required]],
  toTotal: [0, [Validators.Required]],
  option: [value, Validators.required]
}, {validator: EqualsValidator.equals('fromtotal', 'toTotal')});
```

equals.validator.ts:

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export class EqualsValidator {

  /**
   * compares 2 values
   * */
  static equals(valueControlNameA: string, valueControlNameB: string) {
    return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
      // get values
      let valueA = group.get(valueControlNameA).value;
      let valueB = group.get(valueControlNameB).value;

      return valueA === valueB ? null : {equals: true}; 
    }
  }
}
```